# Do Canonical Tags Prevent Google Indexing?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, meta-tags

We're about to embark on a restructuring of our Website, and we will be separating some of our customers into different groups.

Currently all of our customers visit our homepage: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
What we are going to be doing is sending customers to specific landing pages depending on marketing segmentation.

For instance, people who we know are more likely to book a hotel might go to [www.example.com/hotels](http://www.example.com/hotels), whilst people who like cars will go to [www.example.com/cars](http://www.example.com/cars).

The content might be ever so slightly different (a banner or parameter might change) but the vast majority of text (copy, layout) will stay the same.

Firstly, are [Canonical Tags](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) appropriate to use in this case to direct any Google juice back to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)?

Secondly, since we will be marketing to specific groups, we will not want these pages to be indexed by Google, nor for them to appear in search rankings. *With this in mind*, are Canonical Tags still the correct tag to be using? That is, do Canonical Tags pass on the Google Juice to the canonical page, meaning the referrer page is not indexed?

Answer (score 0):

If the core content of all those pages is the same then I think using the canonical tag will work. If Google accepts the canonicalness of the pages then it will always send people to the page you specify.

What do you mean by "sending customers to specific landing pages depending on marketing segmentation"? How is that implemented?

If all that changes is adverts then why not use the one page and dynamically insert the adverts that suit the visitor?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that if you don't want the specific landing pages indexed by Google, or appearing in the search rankings, then the pages wouldn't have any 'Google juice' to consolidate. In that case,  canonical tags won't hurt, but I don't think they'll have any effect.

To keep the landing pages from being indexed, you could use robots.txt, as well as the robots meta tag.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer. The Google Juice I'm trying to consolidate is what's been lost from the customers who would previously have come to www.example.com and now might be going to www.example.com/cars, which is the page we don't want to index. So we'd like to ensure that Google doesn't think that a large chunk of our traffic has dropped off, just because they're now headed to a non-indexed page.